# Flutter : Weird SystemUIOverlayStyle bug

Tags: flutter, dart

I used **SystemChrome** & **AnnotatedRegion** to change some default colors for the status & navigation bars but both didn't work and two problems are found now :

First : The navigation bar background color never changes whatever I do. I thought that the phone I am testing my app on doesn't support changing that color but I opened some chess app on it and it changed that

Two : The status bar icons colors turn from white to black after I use Navigator.pushReplacement even after using the annotated region as a parent for the another route....

Code :

```
import 'package:myapp/pages/loading_page.dart';
import 'package:myapp/statics/statics.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: AppStyles.setDefaultSystemLayout(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: LoadingPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppStyles {
  static SystemUiOverlayStyle setDefaultSystemLayout() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(
      [SystemUiOverlay.bottom, SystemUiOverlay.top],
    );
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      ],
    );
    SystemUiOverlayStyle myStyle = SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: AppColors.background,
      systemNavigationBarColor: AppColors.background,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    );
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(myStyle);
    return myStyle;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am running this code `// Change status bar and navigation bar colors
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Color(0xff263238),
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    ));

    // Change Orientation to be only Portrait.
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);` in the first initState of the first Screen shown up and it works well without the class you make or even `AnnotatedRegion` that.

Comment: @ShadyBoshra What is the android level of your device?

Comment: I used these codes in two application, one of them minSDK is 16 and the other is 19.

Comment: @ShadyBoshra Alright but did you try it on a device that is 16 or 19? and does changing the system navigation bar color requires a permission anyway?

Comment: No it will not work with sdk less than 21.

Comment: @ShadyBoshra I am testing it on 21 and greater but not working... so how about the permission thing?

Comment: No Android permissions needed, did you use my first comment codes ?

Comment: @ShadyBoshra no, they are not different than mine